# How to open js debugger in react native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

I'm new to react native and my goal was to open debugger js in browser. I'm currently setting up my development environment and have encountered a debugging problem.

It is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "jsEngine": "hermes",
    "name": "todo-list",
    "slug": "todo-list",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

package-json

```
{
  "name": "todo-list",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "postcss": "^8.4.23",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.2",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.73.0",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.16.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.1.0",
    "react-devtools": "^5.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

When I try to open debugger through my iphone or console in my idea, I get error "Failed to fetch source map [http://192.168.1.10:19000/node_modules\expo\AppEntry.map?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false](http://192.168.1.10:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.map?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false): remote fetches not permitted".
Actually dont have any idea why there is such an error